# Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined webpack

Tags: веб-программирование, webpack, frontend

только начал изучать webpack, и столкнулся с тем, что вебпак постоянно с нуля собирает проект. Прочитал на хабре статью про кэширование и установил плагин hard-source-webpack-plugin, но он выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined
    at Object.exports.tap (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\hard-source-webpack-plugin\lib\util\plugin-compat.js:118:25)
    at new CacheSerializerFactory (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\hard-source-webpack-plugin\lib\CacheSerializerFactory.js:94:18)
    at HardSourceWebpackPlugin.apply (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\hard-source-webpack-plugin\index.js:219:36)
    at createCompiler (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:71:12)
    at create (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:115:15)
    at webpack (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:123:46)
    at f (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js:35:15)
    at WebpackCLI.createCompiler (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:176:24)
    at WebpackCLI.run (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:268:25)
    at async runCLI (C:\Users\yaaAAAAAA\Desktop\chess\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js:59:9)
```

в чем проблема?